# Versioning in Odoo

Tags: migration, odoo, hook, versioning

I am working on custom addons in Odoo. I have release versions in project. I need hooks, but I need them almost for every release. It will be great to have history of those hooks in code, so I thought about migrations in Odoo. I made migrations directory in my custom addon, I created there directory with release version and there I created some pre-hook.py and post-hook.py with migrate function. I thought that if I will pass to `__manifest__.py` version number then migration hooks will work. I did it and nothing happened. Do You know how to handle versioning in Odoo?